# JasperReports: HTML5 high chart X Axis label font size

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports

I use this command in the advance setting

```
plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.style.fontSize
```

Property value is 20px it seems not working on my stacked bar chart.. can anyone advise the correct way

Comment: You can use xAxis.labels.style and inside it you can set your fontSize. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/omy75p69/1/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the font size of the `X Axis` labels, you'll need to set the `xAxis.labels.style.fontSize` property.  `plotOptions.*.dataLabels` applies to the labels of items inside the plot (when enabled).